# how to fetch root category of one magento store into another?

Tags: php, categories, magento-1.7, magento

I'll tell in short what I'm trying to do so there's no point of confusion.

My website is a daily deal website and city oriented.
In starting I'll be launching my website only for 2 cities. ( includes deals which can be redeemed only in cities )

But their are some shopping deals which is available for every one in the country.

so now what i did is i created 3 stores and 3 root categories at backend. ( 2 for cities and one named as shopping )

I connected the root with the particular stores.

Now if a person is from 3rd city that is not listed in those he would obviously go to the shopping store and find an item for him.

But if the person is from the city listed he will go to his particular city store.
but because of that items available in shopping store won't be visible to him.

so i want a solution so that i can somehow make the Shopping store categories Visible in City stores.
my website: www.dealsburrp.com

Answer (score 0):

With the store id we can get the root-category of a store

```
Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();
```

Comment: bro thanks for your reply :)
is it anyhow possible to contact you?
and do you work as a freelancer?
I'm ready to pay.
My Email: milind.guitarist@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I think firstly we find storeID & using storeId we get rootcategoryid

```
$storeId =Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();

Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();
```